# Smallest unused ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying this quiz on Codewars: [Smallest unused ID](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55eea63119278d571d00006a)

> You've got much data to manage and of course you use zero-based and non-negative ID's to make each data item unique!
>
> Therefore you need a method, which returns the smallest unused ID for your next new data item...
>
> Note: The given array of used IDs may be unsorted. For test reasons there may be duplicate IDs, but you don't have to find or remove them!

In short, You are given an array. What the quiz requires is to find the smallest unused number.

**For example:**

```
[0,1,2,3,5] // Output: 4
[1,2,3,5] // Output: 0
[0,1,2,3,4,5] // Output: 6
[0,0,0,0,0,0] // Output: 1
[0,1,0,2,0,3] // Output: 4
```

My code can't pass some tests. Inputs for the tests are hidden, so I am unable to figure out the causes. What is causing the issue?

```js
const nextId = ids => {
  let lowestId;

  if (Math.max(...ids) + 1 === ids.length) {
    lowestId = Math.max(...ids) + 1;
  } else {
    let sortedIds = ids.sort((a, b) => a - b);

    for (let i = 0; i < sortedIds.length; i++) {
      if (i !== sortedIds[i]) {
        lowestId = i;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return lowestId
}

console.log(nextId([0, 1, 2, 3, 5])) // 4
console.log(nextId([1, 2, 3, 5])) // 0
console.log(nextId([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) // 6
console.log(nextId([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])) // 1
console.log(nextId([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3])) // 4
```

Comment: Please use blockquote markdown for the quoted parts of your question, and say **precisely** what the problem is. For instance, what error is Codewars giving you? A timeout? Some requirement not met? What?

Comment: After sorting, just `find` the number which is not equal to index? If it returns undefined, then return `array.length`

Comment: @adiga - If you even have to sort. The example inputs are sorted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the link mentions about unsorted arrays and OP's code has `sort`

Comment: @adiga - Perils of relying on external links for question content. :-)

Comment: Thank you for comments. I added some inputs. In JavaScript mode, only two inputs are shown, but I have found that more inputs are shown in other languages.

Comment: The issue you currently have is that you're relying on there not being any duplicates in the sorted array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're over complicating it

```
    function doStuff(stuff)
    {
        for(let i = 0; i < stuff.length + 1; i++)
        {
            if(stuff.indexOf(i) == -1)
                return i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) I am sorry but I added some inputs to the examples after this answer was posted. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look at it.

Comment: It works with all the console.log examples you provided so I don't know what you're asking for now

Comment: Ah! Thank you. It passed tests by changing the function name from `doStuff` to `nextId` :)

Comment: includes would be better

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you missed this line of the instructions:

"Note: The given array of used IDs may be unsorted. For test reasons there may be duplicate IDs, but you don't have to find or remove them!"

With the logic of your code, if there's a duplicate then the value won't match the index. You need to actually compare the values to account for duplicates.

```
function nextId(ids) {
  let lowestId = 0;
  let sortedIds = ids.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  for (let i = 0; i < sortedIds.length; i++) {
    if (lowestId === sortedIds[i] && lowestId !== sortedIds[i + 1]) {
      lowestId++;
    }
    else if (lowestId !== sortedIds[i + 1]) {
      return lowestId;
    }
  }
  return lowestId
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach takes an object for seen values.

The start node is `-1`, because the first missing `id` could be zero.

Performance:

- To collect all nodes: **O(n)**.
- To find the missing smallest `id`: smaller than **O(n)**.

```js
function nextId(ids){
    const seen = {};
    let id = -1;
  
    for (const id of ids) seen[id] = true;
  
    while (seen[++id]) ;
    return id;
}

console.log(nextId([0, 1, 2, 3, 5])); // 4
console.log(nextId([1, 2, 3, 5])); // 0
console.log(nextId([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // 6
console.log(nextId([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])); // 1
console.log(nextId([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3])); // 4
```